# how to upload a web project with external jar in wildfly 11?

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly, wildfly-11

I need to upload my web project to Wildfly 11. The first time I tried to upload my project without external libraries and it worked correctly, but when I add new libraries it no longer allows me to upload in wildfly 11. the project runs fine if I run it as java in the Eclipse IDE.I generated war with export project in eclipse, the error that comes out is the following.

```
    21:22:43,137 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."ApiPolizaApesegTest.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."ApiPolizaApesegTest.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "ApiPolizaApesegTest.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:172)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class imp.ws.soatcimtc.rimac.soap.SOAPImpl with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.ApiPolizaApesegTest.war" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:78)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:106)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:91)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:165)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/Request
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.Request from [Module "deployment.ApiPolizaApesegTest.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    ... 15 more

21:22:43,142 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 6) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "ApiPolizaApesegTest.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"ApiPolizaApesegTest.war\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"ApiPolizaApesegTest.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class imp.ws.soatcimtc.rimac.soap.SOAPImpl with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.ApiPolizaApesegTest.war\" from Service Module Loader
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/Request
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.Request from [Module \"deployment.ApiPolizaApesegTest.war\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
21:22:43,144 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (External Management Request Threads -- 6) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "ApiPolizaApesegTest.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"ApiPolizaApesegTest.war\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"ApiPolizaApesegTest.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class imp.ws.soatcimtc.rimac.soap.SOAPImpl with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.ApiPolizaApesegTest.war\" from Service Module Loader
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/Request
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.Request from [Module \"deployment.ApiPolizaApesegTest.war\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
```

I think that I might not recognize the external libraries, I add the libraries by jar

Answer (score 1):

You need to package your "external libraries" into your war and redeploy the application using the new war.
Also WildFly 11 is quite old, I would recommend to upgrade to WildFly 23.